# Unwanted information being displayed in a text label from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, string

[image]weird and probabaly a stupid question here.
Essentially I'm taking a NSString and applying it to a text label. However, there's alot of added information that I didn't ask for. I'm hoping to get someones input on what I might be doing wrong.
Here's the code for setting the text label.

```
NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@.%@.%@", firstOctetString, addedSecondOctet, thirdOctetString, fourthOctetString];
    self.newlyConstructedIPAddressLabel.text = finalString;
    NSLog(@"%@", finalString);
```

The output that's being inserted into that label is actually shown as:

```
2016-03-29 09:42:43.461 TestIPConstruct[31207:1667950] <UILabel: 0x7ff571422540; frame = (20 275; 335 21); text = '10.83.223.71'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7ff571422750>>
```

any idea's on why this might be happening would be fantastic.
Thanks,
- Nate

Comment: can you show a screenshot ? I'm sure you are seeing that in the debugger.

Comment: the label text is being set to the NSLog output of the label description itself (where that log output shows the IP address having been set as the text)?

Comment: The debugger is actually showing exactly what's being printed into the text label. Which is odd...

Comment: @Wain my question is then, I just removed that NSLog statement and that didn't alter the issue :/

Comment: pls attach a screenshot of the issue.!

Comment: i'd have to guess that you have a memory corruption somewhere as even setting the text of the label to the description of the label wouldn't include the timestamp. i'd probably fire up instruments and run some memory, leaks and allocation tests

Comment: @TejaNandamuri screenshot added above. Please review.

Comment: You put the label as the second argument when constructing the NSString. I'd image writing self.originalIPAddressLabel.text should fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately changing from self.newlyConstructedIPAddress.text didn't work. Still printing the same thing. The runIPAddressChange is actually called by an IBAction from a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting `originalIPAddressLabel` from:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.originalIPAddressLabel];
```

This has the effect of calling `[self.originalIPAddressLabel description]` which will contain debugging information about the label object, which you are seeing even after processing the text.

Use this instead:

```
NSString *originalIPAddressLabel = self.originalIPAddressLabel.text;
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. Let me understand, what you're saying is setting the self.originalIPAddressLabel as a literal is actually causing debugging info to show up when I am setting the newlyConstructedIPAddressLabel?

Comment: I think I see what you're saying...one moment.

Comment: Spot on!! Nice, that worked fantastically. I see what you were saying, when I called self.originalIPAddressLabel in the IPAddressChange method debug information was then being called.